# Output panel too small in Sublime Text 3 with Material Theme

Tags: resize, output, sublimetext3, panel, material-design

When I use the default theme of Sublime Text 3, the output panel can be resized normally. But when I switch to Material Theme, I can no longer adjust the size of the output panel. It's just one line height, so I have scroll to up to see the whole result, which is really inconvenient. How can I adjust the settings so that I can still resize the output panel with Material Theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have to Right-click the editing area of an opening file, select *Material Theme* -> *Configuration* -> *Panels* -> tick the **material_theme_compact_panel** option.